# PHPExcel removes Data Validation Option of Excel sheet after editing existing Excel Sheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using `PHPExcel` for editing existing excel sheets.

I had already set up a Data Validation method in my excel sheet as below.
[image]

When i edit this excel using `PHPExcel`, this Excel Specific Data Validation vanishes.

Can anyone help me to overcome this issue. I need to edit the excel without changing its functionality.

**My PHP code:**

```
 //load existing template..
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('www/PHPExcelReader/Excel_Uploads/sample.xls');

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Logic Item")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Logic")
                             ->setTitle("List");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('AZ1', $combination);

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$file_name='sample.xls';
$objWriter->save($file_name);
echo "Excel is ready to download now...";
```

Comment: Are you using `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);` with this?

Comment: Why don't you open an issue on GitHub if Mark's suggestion doesn't help? https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues

Comment: @MarkBaker : I am NOT using `setReadDataOnly(true)` as i am only writing data into excel. I updated question with full code .please check

Comment: Unable to replicate this problem, can you please provide a spreadsheet file that demonstrates the issue

Comment: @MarkBaker: I am unable to attach the xls file here. Please provide email id.
How did i create the issue is, `I had set up an validation on A1 cell from G1:G4 cells. Intially G1:G4 is empty so A1 will show one blank dropdown list. Then i am writing G1:G4 using PHPExcel , values are written but A1 cell does not have the validation.`

Comment: @MarkBaker : I sent the files to email id. As i said, if G1:G4 is empty initially its not working. but if it has atleast one value before writing then its working. Try with my excel with your code.

Answer (score 0):

From spreadsheet files that I've just created with data validation on cell A1 applying values from a list in $G1:$G4 and the following code:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = './15datavalidationUnpopulated.xls';
$outputFileType = 'Excel5';
$outputFileName = './15datavalidationPopulated.xls';

$objPHPExcelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelReader->load($inputFileName);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', "India")
                              ->setCellValue('G2', "America")
                              ->setCellValue('G3', "China")
                              ->setCellValue('G4', "Russia");

$objPHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,$outputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelWriter->save($outputFileName);
```

works with both .xls and .xlsx files, showing India, America, China and Russia in the data validation dropdown list for cell A1

Comment: I sent the files to your email id. As i said, if G1:G4 is empty initially its not working. but if it has atleast one value before writing then its working. Try with my excel with above code.